# Visual Studio 2015 caching Web API project URL

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am having this weird issue with VS 2015 Update 3 while running Web API project via IIS Express. Here are the steps I followed

1> Start Visual Studio 2015 (with Update 3)
2> Select new Asp.NET 4.6.2 web project
3> Select Empty Project - > and check Web.API check box
4> Once the solution is ready then create new Controller using `Web API2 Controller with read/write actions`  and name the controller `DocumentController`
5>The routeTemplate is set as `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"` at project startup.
6> Press F5 to run the application
7> Visual studio host the API in IIS express as `http://localhost:53394` so I type `http://localhost:53394/api/document` and I see some json result in the browser as expected.
8> Now i change API project's project URL from `http://localhost:53394` to `http://localhost:53394/api/document` hoping I don't have to type whole url everytime. When I change the URL I get prompt

[image]

I select yes. However that doesn't work. In-fact now my URL becomes `http://localhost:53394/api/document/api/document`

9> So I change the project URL back to what it was `http://localhost:53394`. This time it didn't prompt me.

10>Now when I try to access the api using`http://localhost:53394/api/document` I get error

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>
> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this
>   directory

but if I access api using URL `http://localhost:53394/api/document/api/document` then I get result back.

I have tried restarting visual studio, clearing browsers history with no luck
Not sure why & where VS caching URL.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio isn't caching any URL.

Change your project settings' url back to `http://localhost:53394/`. This is the **root** url of the website.

Next, you'll need to clean up your IIS Express configs. You can mess around with the XML if you're up for it. I find it best to just delete the folders. VS will recreate them anyways.

These configs are located in a special folder named `.vs` that's in the same folder as your solution file. It's hidden, so you'll need to `Show hidden files` in Windows Explorer. (Note to any other readers, this is specific to VS 2015. In earlier version of VS, these configs are in an IIS Express folder in AppData.)

After this, you should recreate the virtual directory, and try again. Update your question with the results if this doesn't work.